# Ref template doesn't bind to apexchart diagram

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, apexcharts

First of all, I am new to ApexCharts.js. My setup is vue3 app using Composition API and `setup` syntax. What I am trying to do is to refer template ref of `apexchart` so I can further call dataURI() function on it. I'm trying to call it from `onMounted`.
What I get is exception `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'dataURI')`

This is what I've tried. Chart options and series are omitted

```
<script setup lang="ts">
...
import ApexCharts from 'apexcharts'

const chart = ref({} as ApexCharts);

onMounted(async () => {
    await chart.value.dataURI().then(({ imgURI, blob }) => {
        console.log("...")
    });
});
</script>

<template>
    <div>
        <div id="chart">
            <apexchart ref="chart" :options="options" :series="series" type="polarArea" :size="200" />
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: It looks like adding nextTick() before calling dataURI() almost did the trick. By "almost" I mean that I got image, but only with the legend and axes, not actual data. It looks like the chart is not completly rendered?

Answer (score 0):

I think chart is not correctly initialized when you are trying to access its methods. Try initializing it in **onMounted** lifecycle hook.

```js
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';
import ApexCharts from 'apexcharts';

const chart = ref(null);
const options = { chart: { type: 'polarArea' };
const series = [14, 23, 21, 17, 15, 10, 12, 17, 21];

onMounted(async () => {
  chart.value = new ApexCharts(document.getElementById('chart'), {
    chart: {
      type: 'polarArea',
      height: 200,
    },
    series,
  });

  await chart.value.render();
  
  const { imgURI, blob } = chart.value.dataURI();
  console.log('Data URI:', imgURI);
});
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div id="chart">
      <apexchart ref="chart" :options="options" :series="series" type="polarArea" :size="200" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```